# Ben Ish Chai: Rome and the USA

Tags: sources-mekorot, messianic-redemption, masechet-yoma, masecheth-avodah-zarah, ben-ish-chai

Rav Daniel Glatstein often quotes from the Ben Ish Chai's commentary Ben Yehoyada on Avodah Zarah 10. He says that the Ben Yehoyada describes "רוֹמִי"- Rome - to mean "Western ideas" and "The United States". I have searched on [Sefaria](https://www.sefaria.org/Ben_Yehoyada_on_Avodah_Zarah.10b.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), but could not find where this idea is written down.

Does anyone know where to find this Ben Yehoyada?

See also [here](https://www.theyeshivaworld.com/news/general/40818/torahs-view-on-iran-eretz-yisroel-america-moshiach.html), where  he supposedly have said that Rome refers to:

> Western Super-Power—America.

Answer (score 4):

It's from [Ben Yehoyada to Avodah Zarah 10a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ben_Yehoyada_on_Avodah_Zarah.10a?lang=bi):

> וכאשר תמצא עתה כי מלכות של אמריכאן אין להם לשון משלהם אלא לקחו הלשון ממלכות של אנגליז דקדים להו והם מדברים עתה בלשון אנגליז מלכות ברטאניה וכך קים להו לרבנן דאותם רומאי שהיו בזמן הקודם לקחו הלשון והמכתב שלהם ממלכות אחרת
>
> And nowadays we find that the USA has no language of their own, and they took their language from the Kingdom of England which came before them, and they now speak the English of the Kingdom of Britain. And the Rabbis knew that the Romans who existed in ancient times took their language and their script from another kingdom.

Comment: So he's just making a limited comparison? He's not saying the US is specifically Edom (and in the 19th century it would be no more significant than Britain or Germany anyway)

Comment: @JoelK exactly what Aka wrote. Thanks, but is this the Ben Ish Chai saying that USA represents Edom due to western ideology?

Comment: How many countries are there whose languages did *not* come from some other ancient or modern polity? "The UK has no language of their own, and they took it from various Germanic countries" (Anglo-Saxon settlement, c. 400–600). Or perhaps from the Norman's (c. 1000). Latin script came from Etruscan (I assume that is what is referenced), but that came from Euboan Greek script. And the very Hebrew in which he wrote came from proto-Sinaitic scripts which almost certainly took a lot of inspiration from ancient Egyptian hieroglyphs.

Comment: @JoelK so maybe, this Ben Yehoyada is interpreted to mean "western ideology"? Because I can't seem to read that in the commentary.